# How can I send pre-recorded audio files as recorded audio on Telegram using Python?

Tags: python-requests, file-extension, telegram-api

How to send a pre-recorded audio file by Telegram, but it has to look like a recording, using Python?

Hello, I am not an expert programming, I do it for fun, I hope you can help me.

I'm trying to create a simple python script to read a friend's message (Telegram chat), choose the appropriate audio file and send it; all done automatically.

The audio files are pre-recorded but doing tests I realized that when sending the pre-recorded file (.mp3) the icon is different than if I was sending it as recorded audio at that moment with the telegram app (unknown file extension, maybe .ogg ).

Maybe sending the file with the correct extension can fix the problem. Does anyone know what the correct extension is? I hope it's not encoded.

I have tried to use the function`/sendaudio <file>` without success

To read the chat messages, I used the telegram API. I don't want to use Bots because from what I understand I have to include it in the chat as an additional participant or a separate chat.